# Zimbra sends alarms for service restarts by its cronjobs

Tags: cron, anti-virus, zimbra

I'm trying to solve an issue where we get ~8 nightly mails from Zimbra OSE 8.

They'll look i.e. like this one:

```
Dec 21 00:46:15 hostname zmconfigd[16202]: Service status change:
exhostname amavis changed from stopped to running
```

The mails appear for the services `amavis` and `antispam`.

These mails inform of service status changes. The status changes are i.e. caused by setting up updates of ClamAV antivirus or the Spam Assassin rulesets along with the respective daemon restarts.
So, those restarts are something that must occur if you did your housekeeping proper.
(Which is not mandatory)

I've already spend multiple hours trying to find any good approach for how to avoid these mails. I would much rather disable the whole service monitoring than having 8 false positives from it every other night.